# Что такое зеркальное дерево

Tags: структуры

Объясните пожалуйста, что такое зеркальное отражение бинарного дерева. Если можно с примером, даже нелепым.

Answer (score 0):

Дерево и его зеркальное отражение

```
  3          3
 / \        / \ 
6   5      5   6 
   /        \
  1          1
```

Comment: элементы в узлах дожны обязательно должны быть одинаковые?

Comment: Да, конечно, ну а как же иначе?